# After upgrading to Angular 6, material 6, select option event fired continuously and browser hangs. How to stop unwanted emit events?

Tags: angular-material, angular-material2, angular6, rxjs6

In below code, my country select options are fired so many times that browser stopped responding.

```
<div [formGroup]="countryForm">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select formControlName="selectedCountry" class="my-item-text" placeholder="Country">
      <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="onCountrySelectionChanged($event)" *ngFor="let myCountry of countries" [value]="myCountry.short" class="my-item-text">{{ myCountry.name }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

and my component code as below

```
  onCountrySelectionChanged(changeEvent) {
    if (changeEvent && changeEvent.isUserInput && this.selectedCountry != changeEvent.source.value) {
      this.countrySelected.emit( changeEvent.source.value);
    }
  }
```

I tried to restrict by checking if its user change event [isUserInput] and also checking if the value really changed! Now am able to reduce the fire-events and the application works normal.

Is there a better way to use select-option as am now including above logic everywhere am using mat-select component.

Answer (score 5):

The `mat-select` has an Output property you can bind to called `selectionChange`, which should fire whenever the option is changed by the user. Try switching up your code to this:

```
<div [formGroup]="countryForm">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select (selectionChange)="onCountrySelectionChanged($event)" formControlName="selectedCountry" class="my-item-text" placeholder="Country">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let myCountry of countries" [value]="myCountry.short" class="my-item-text">{{ myCountry.name }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Thinking about it - what's probably happened is that you've put your `onSelectionChange` binding on every single `mat-option`, so when you change the option, you're likely firing that once for each option in your select. Moving it out to the `mat-select` means it will only fire once.